Which bits do I need to extract in a signed fixed point multiplier?
I need to design a fixed point multiplier in Verilog that takes in a 16 bif formatted with one sign bit, 6 integer bits and 7 fractional bits. I just can't figure out which bits to extract to ensure an accurate answer.
module signed_fixed_point_multiplier(
    input signed [15:0] a,
    input signed [15:0] b,
    output signed [15:0] result
);
    wire sign_bit;
    wire [6:0] a_dec, b_dec;
    wire [7:0] a_frac, b_frac;
    wire signed [31:0] temp_result;

    
    assign sign_bit = a[15] ^ b[15]; // XOR the sign bits to get the sign
    assign signed temp_result = a * b; // Multiply the fixed-point numbers
    always @(*) begin
        if (temp_result[31] != temp_result[30]) begin
            // Overflow occurred if the sign bit of the result is not the same as the bit before it
            overflow = 1;
        end else begin
            overflow = 0;
        end
    end
endmodule


To express the number of integer and fractional bits we use Q number format: Qi.f where i is the number of integer bits and f is the number of fractional bits. 100100.1100011 has six integer and seven fractional bits, so it is Q6.7 (excluding the sign bit). In your case your input is 16 bits so lets say 2 bits are redundant sign bits i.e. 16'SS_S_iiiiii.fffffff where S represent the sign of the number.
Now when a Q6.7 number is added in a Q6.7 number then the resultant is Q7.7 number. Similarly, if a Q6.7 number is multiplied with a Q6.7 number, we get Q12.14 number. (This is known as bit growth).
Now let se how the math works with an example of Q4.4 numbers:
Addition & Subtraction:
Addition works in exactly the same way as for integers:
  0011.1010        3.6250
+ 0100.0001      + 4.0625
= 0111.1011      = 7.6875

We can also do subtraction using two’s complement to express the negative number:
  0011.1010        3.6250
+ 1110.1000      - 1.5000
= 0010.0010      = 2.1250

How do we get the two’s complement for -1.5?
1.5 = 1 + 1/2 = 0001.1000

Start:  0001.1000 (1.5)
Invert: 1110.0111
Add 1:  0000.0001
Result: 1110.1000 (-1.5)

Multiplication:
Multiplication works as expected too, but the product contains twice the number of bits. Multiplying two Q4.4 numbers results in a Q8.8 product:
  0011.0100           3.2500
x 0010.0001           2.0625
  00000110.10110100 = 6.703125

We can round this to our original Q4.4 format by taking the eight middle bits:
0000[0110.1011]0100 = 0110.1011 = 6.6875

Overflow:
All results so far have fitted in our Q4.4 representation, but this doesn’t always happen. Let’s consider what happens when we multiply 6.5 by 4:
  0110.1000          6.5000
x 0100.0000          4.0000
  00011010.00000000  26.0000

So now if we pick the Q4.4  numbers around the point, then we will get 1010.0000 which is incorrect. This is because of the overflow condition and this is something to be dealt with.
Now you want to multiply two Q6.7 numbers, then the resultant will be Q12.14, as a result of bit growth. Since you want your answer in the same Q6.7 range then you just pick the 6 digits from the left of the point and 7 digits from the right of the point. In this case the point is going to be after the 14th digit (i.e. between bit 14 and 13), so you can pick temp_result[20:7]. But you need to be caution if the overflow occurs, because the actual result is in Q12.14 bits but you are only selection Q6.7 bits.
Next thing is you have to take care of the sign as well, if sign is positive, then you can send the results to the output as it is but if the sign is negative, then you will have to take 2's complement before sending it to the output.
assign result = S ? {S, S, S, Two_Complement_of_temp_result[20:7]} : {S, S, S, temp_result[20:7]}; //S represents the sign bits.


Here are the steps that you should follow for the multiplication:

Convert the inputs into positive numbers (check the sign bit if it is 1, take the 2's complement of the number.)
Multiply the numbers (using unsigned multiplier)
Convert the output into Q6.7 format and be aware of the overflow condition.
Check the sign of the output based on inputs sign (i.e. a[15] ^ b[15])
Take the 2's complement of the output if negative sign is required at the output.


The post is ambiguous WRT the total number of bits at the input;  one sign bit + 6 integer bits + 7 fractional bits = 14 bits, however there is a 16 bit bus.
I will provide an answer based on 16 bits, signed, 8 fractional assuming that the code snip input signed [15:0] a defines the format.
If 16 bits are multiplied by 16 bits the result is 32 bits.  You can search 'fixed point multiplication' or see my favorite Zip Cpu Bit Growth for more about fpga arithmetic.

...I just can't figure out which bits to extract to ensure an accurate answer.

Using less than 32 bits at the output results in a loss of precision.
There is no overflow when using a full precision (in this case 32 bit) output.
If you use a slice (subsection < 32 bits) of that 32 bit output, then there is the loss of precision an the LSB's and a possibility of saturation/overflow at the MSB's.  There are associated design choices which can be made (saturation or roll over at the MSB's, rounding or truncation at the LSB's).
Here is an example where I calculate a full precision mul (output c), and grab a slice of the full precision, then interpret the results as fixed point numbers by scaling by 2^NUMBER_FRACTIONAL_BITS.  I choose a slice justified to the left so there is no saturation or rollover possible, and I truncated at the LSB's.
RTL
module sfpm
  (
    input wire signed  [15:0] a,
    input wire signed  [15:0] b,
    output reg signed  [31:0] c,
    output reg signed  [15:0] result
  );

  assign c = a * b;
  assign result = c[31:16];
  
endmodule

Testbench
module tb ();
  
  logic signed [15:0] a,b,result;
  logic signed [31:0] c;
  
  localparam NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT = 8;
  localparam NUM_FRACT_BITS_OUTPUT = NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT * 2;
  
  task printAndScaleIt();
    $monitor("a b c result -> %f %f %f %f", 
            $itor(a)/(2**NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT),$itor(b)/(2**NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT),
              $itor(c)/(2**NUM_FRACT_BITS_OUTPUT),$itor(result));    
  endtask
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    printAndScaleIt();
    a = 1.5*(2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    b = 1.5*(2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    #1;
    //
    a = -1.25*(2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    b =  1.25*(2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    //
    #1;
    a =   1.25  * (2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    b = - 1.125 * (2 ** NUM_FRACT_BITS_INPUT);
    //
    #1;
  end
  
  sfpm dut(.*);
  
endmodule

Produces
a b c result = 1.500000 1.500000 2.250000 2.000000    
a b c result = -1.250000 1.250000 -1.562500 -2.000000    
a b c result = 1.250000 -1.125000 -1.406250 -2.00000    

You can see the resulting loss of precision when we truncate to the right of the decimal point.  The full precision output is 2.25, the slice result is 2.0 because we have thrown away bits (truncated).

It seems like you are unclear about how to interpret the output answer in terms of where the decimal point should be.

I just can't figure out which bits to extract to ensure an accurate answer.

In general, if you have N fractional bits * M fractional bits, then the result will have M + N fractional bits.  In my example there are 16 fractional bits.
Going back to the numbers expressed in the text of your post,

...one sign bit, 6 integer bits and 7 fractional bits

The full precision result would have 7 + 7 = 14 fractional bits, and
(1 + 6 + 7) + (1 + 6 + 7) = 28 total bits.  Anything less than 28 bits results a loss of precision.

Waves

You can see that the waves just show the integer value of the bit vectors, they must be converted to real values & scaled by 2 ** SCALE_FACTOR to obtain the fixed point decimal values.
